# Do I need several wordpress installation to create a wordpress website with several admin?

Tags: wordpress

I am planning to create a new website for an organization. We will be several administrators.

Should I plan to install Wordpress on several computers (with different OS), or can I install Wordpress only once, with asking the other contributors to manage the site online?

Meanwhile, my idea is to use a subdirectory of our actual website to create the new one, before replace the old one. Is it a good idea?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just curious if you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you've indicated in your question if this is for an organization you could take WordPress and create a WordPress Multisite.  WordPress does have some documentation on [Creating a Network](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network).  Multi-site will allow you to be the Super Admin and you could create a site for each department with their individual admins.

[Roles and Capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)

[image]

A few helpful links to read:

- [The Ultimate Guide to WordPress Multisite](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/ultimate-guide-multisite/)
- [How to Activate Multisite](https://premium.wpmudev.org/manuals/creating-a-network-to-enable-wordpress-multisite/)
- [How to Install and Setup WordPress Multisite Network](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-wordpress-multisite-network/)
- [What is: Multisite (MU)](http://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/multisite/)

---

If you only want one site with multiple users and need some admin features you can setup custom roles with [`add_role( $role, $display_name, $capabilities );`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role).  There are some right-ups on Custom Roles, one I referenced was [How to Create Custom User Roles in WordPress](https://managewp.com/create-custom-user-roles-wordpress).

---

From comments:

You can build one site with several admins but you should be careful having several admins. One admin can delete other admins and take full control of the site or accidentally cause issues to the site.

To set this up in a directory all you would need to do is install a WP instance in that directory of your choosing but setup your database for it before hand and follow the install procedure. Before building so many admins I think you should review the roles to see if you don't need them to be editors.

Answer (score 0):

No, WordPress instances can have multiple user accounts with different user types from admins to editors to other limited capabilities.

Comment: So I don't need several installation. And about my second question. Is it a good idea to use a subdirectory to work? I think I an online space to share in order to be able to share the work.